# cannot reference before supertype has been called java

Tags: java, constructor, instance

I have a class `Ship`

```
public class Ship {

    private String name;
    private boolean loaded;
    private int size;
    private boolean bIsDefeated;
    private int gunpower;

    public Ship(int size, int gunpower, String name) {
        this.size = size;
        this.gunpower = gunpower;
        this.name= name;
        loaded = true;
        bIsDefeated = false;
    }
}
```

and `Submarine`

```
class Submarine extends Ship {

    private final String NAME = "U-Boot";
    private final int SIZE = 2;
    private final int GUNPOWER = 1;

    public Submarine(){
        super(SIZE,GUNPOWER,NAME);  //Here it gets underlined
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why that is not possible?

Comment: and what exactly is the error you are seeing?  It is not clear from the title of your question.

Comment: `NAME` is not static and can't be called at that point.

Comment: Love the downvotes for all the answers.  Thanks

Comment: I have updated it. I had to translate the code first to let you understand it more easily, obvieously i forgot some words to translate. I have no idea about the downvotes, did not do them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public UBoot(){
   super(SIZE,GUNPOWER,NAME);
}
```

Looks like you're trying to make a constructor with a different name than the class.  Try a `static factory method`

```
public static Submarine uboot() {
    // something like
    Submarine s = new Submarine(UBOAT_SIZE, UBOAT_GUNPOWER, "UBoat");
    return s;
}
```

where `UBOAT_SIZE` and `UBOAT_GUNPOWDER` are `private static final int` variables in your class

and `Ship`'s constructor is wrong

```
this.bezeichnung = name;
```

Should be

```
this.name = name;
```

EDIT

Okay you've changed your question now...

```
private final String NAME = "U-Boot";
private final int SIZE = 2;
private final int GUNPOWER = 1;

public Submarine(){
    super(SIZE,GUNPOWER,NAME);  //Here it gets underlined
}
```

`SIZE`, `GUNPOWDER`, and `NAME` all need to be `private static final ...` variables because you don't have an instance of Submarine at the time of the constructor -- so they must be `static`

Answer (score 0):

Change `NAME` to `static`

```
class Submarine extends Ship {

    private final static String NAME = "U-Boot";
    private final static int SIZE = 2;
    private final static int GUNPOWER = 1;

    public Submarine() {
        super(SIZE, GUNPOWER, NAME);
    }
```

I presume your constructor name issue was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Your submarine constructor is wrong

```
public UBoot(){
    super(SIZE,GUNPOWER,NAME);
}
```

Must be

```
public Submarine(){
    super(SIZE,GUNPOWER,NAME);
}
```

**UPDATE** as pointed `NAME` variable should be `static`

Comment: I've noticed that happening today, on some questions answers will simply get downvoted randomly for no apparent reason. Looks to be someone abusing the system.

Comment: looks weird... all seem valid questions

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

There is no `UBoot` class but `Submarine`:

```
public UBoot(){
        super(SIZE,GUNPOWER,NAME);
}
```

should be

```
public Submarine(){
            super(SIZE,GUNPOWER,NAME);
}
```

and

there is no field named `bezeichnung`.

This:

```
this.bezeichnung = name;
```

should be:

```
this.name = name;
```

`NAME` should be `static` so this:

```
private final String NAME = "U-Boot";
```

should be:

```
private static final String NAME = "U-Boot";
```